# Usage of extends in Class, Abstract, Interface combination

Tags: java, generics, collections

My main question revolves around when to use and what is the difference between the following when combined with Class, Abstract, Interface:

1. `<E>`
2. `<E extends Interface>`
3. `<? extends Interface>`

Shown below is a detailed question with some code signatures:

This code uses Guava Forwarding Decorators to define specific collections.

Base Interface:

```
public interface AnimalSetInterface<E extends AnimalI> extends Set<E>
```

This works:

```
public interface AsiaI<E extends AnimalI> extends AnimalSetInterface<E>
```

The following gives an error:

```
public interface AsiaI<E> extends AnimalSetInterface<E>
```

> Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded
>   parameter  of the type AnimalSetInterface

What I am trying to understand is if I have specified at the Base Interface that I only want `<E extends AnimalI>` then why do I have to specify again in `AsiaI`?

I am trying to understand generics and at the same time minimize code.

Also if both classes have such code is there a good way to combine/minimize (remove/generify boilerplate code) it:
**Asia:**

```
public Asia(final ImmutableSet<E> animalSet){
    super(animalSet);
}

public static <E extends AnimalI> AsiaI<E> of(final ImmutableSet<E> animalSet){
    return new Asia(animalSet);
}
```

**Africa:**

```
public Africa(final ImmutableSet<E> animalSet){
    super(animalSet);
}

public static <E extends AnimalI> AfricaI<E> of(final ImmutableSet<E> animalSet){
    return new Africa(animalSet);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 public class Africa<E extends AnimalI> extends AnimalSetAbstract implements AfricaI

 public class Asia<E> extends AnimalSetAbstract implements AsiaI
```

The difference is that in the first case, your generic type must extend AnimalI
In the second case, your generic type could be any class.

Comment: That's what I thought but the following usage gives error (which is what I want):   

`final AsiaI<String> a = new Asia(ImmutableSet.of()); // <String> should not work`

Comment: @PranavShah could you please update your question with the desired behaviour. Isn't clear for me so far what's your problem.

Comment: On further inspection I see what's going on.  In my test code I was using interface instead of the class, and thus i was getting the error, but now I think I understand what's going on